# How to avoid N+1 Queries for this code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been struggling to figure out how to avoid using so many SQL queries from this code. I'm taking in Collect objects via an API with Shopify, and then checking if there's a match already in my local database, and if not then creating a new local Collect object with parameters from my local matching Product and Collection. I wasn't sure how I would use includes or join because I'm doing a lookup and not just getting a value inside of the loop. Any pointers are welcomed.

```
  def seed_collects!
    shop = self.with_shopify!
    c = (1..(ShopifyAPI::Collect.count.to_f/250.0).ceil).flat_map do |page|
      ShopifyAPI::Collect.find(:all, :params => {:page => page.to_i, :limit => 150})
    end
    c.each do |collect|
      next if Collect.find_by(shopify_collect_id: collect.id)
      product = Product.find_by(shopify_product_id: collect.product_id.to_s)
      collection = Collection.find_by(shopify_collection_id: collect.collection_id.to_s)
      col = Collect.new(shopify_collect_id: collect.id,
                        position: collect.position,
                        product_id: product.id,
                        collection_id: collection.id)  
      col.save
      puts col.errors.inspect if col.errors.any?
    end
  end
```

Schema

```
  create_table "collections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "shopify_collection_id"
    t.string   "collection_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
    t.integer  "shop_id"
  end

  create_table "collects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "position"
    t.string   "shopify_collect_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "collection_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "shopify_product_id"
    t.string   "product_type"
    t.string   "tags"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "shop_id"
    t.string   "main_image_src"
  end
```

Models

```
class Collect < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :collection

  delegate :shop, to: :product
  delegate :shopify_product_id, to: :product 
  delegate :shopify_collection_id, to: :collection 
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  # verify all items belong to shop
  belongs_to :shop #verify
  has_many :collects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :collects

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :variants, ->{ order(:created_at) }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :price_tests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :metrics, ->{ order(:created_at) }, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :collects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :collections, through: :collects
```

Comment: How do your these models look like?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, not sure what you’re asking for? The models have data structures that match the scheme I posted.

Comment: I saw that you have `product_id` in `collects` but it is actually `shopify_product_id` not `product.id` in `products` table. Hence, I would like to checkout association between collections, collects, products in model.

Comment: Please post models over here

Comment: Just posted them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to avoid N+1 in your case is to bulk-fetch collects, products, collections. Please try below code:

```
def seed_collects!
  shop = self.with_shopify!
  c = (1..(ShopifyAPI::Collect.count.to_f/250.0).ceil).flat_map do |page|
    ShopifyAPI::Collect.find(:all, :params => {:page => page.to_i, :limit => 150})
  end

  shopify_collect_ids    = c.map(&:id)
  shopify_product_ids    = c.map(&:product_id)
  shopify_collection_ids = c.map(&:collection_id)

  collects    = Collect.where(shopify_collect_id: shopify_collect_ids).pluck(:shopify_collect_id, :id)
  collect_ids = Hash[collects]

  products    = Product.where(shopify_product_id: shopify_product_ids).pluck(:shopify_product_id, :id)
  product_ids = Hash[products]

  collections    = Collection.where(shopify_collection_id: shopify_collection_ids).pluck(:shopify_collection_ids, :id)
  collection_ids = Hash[collections]

  c.each do |collect|
    next if collect_ids[collect.id]
    col = Collect.new(shopify_collect_id: collect.id,
                      position: collect.position,
                      product_id: product_ids[collect.product_id.to_s],
                      collection_id: collection_ids[collect.collection_id.to_s])  
    col.save
    puts col.errors.inspect if col.errors.any?
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible typo: isn't the paging limit on line 4 meant to be 250 (i.e. the same as on line 3)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll give this code a shot tonight!!